# Sort music files by disc number in Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-explorer, music, tags

I'm working under Vista and the problem is—I can see disc number of track in Winamp or other multimedia player, but I cannot sort files by disc number in Windows Explorer.

I've scanned through the whole long list of available properties of files but haven't found "disc number" or similar property.

So is there any way to sort tracks by disc number in Windows Explorer, and if there is, then how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there is a field for this, it's just called somewhat unusual: *part of set*.